# How to use variables in grafana as full match not as regex?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a query variable in Grafana and I wish to use it in where clause to filter my results. It seems only to work as `WHERE ("tag" =~ /^$variable$/)`, but I do not wish to use regex match since it slows down my query unnecessarily.
So I am looking for something like `WHERE ("tag" = $variable)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
WHERE ("tag" = '${variable:raw}')
```

It will insert raw value - no magic variable formatting will be used.